# Extract data from url with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, url, extract

EDIT_2: I forgot to specify its for Android app, so i dont think this is any use, i made a new post instead :( Added Android TAG..

EDIT: Im making an Android App

I need help to extract a number from an url, generated by JavaScript!

Site is:
http://www.oddsportal.com/sure-bets/

And the path looks like this:

```
<a href="/bookmaker/paddy-power/surebet/" title="Paddy Power" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;"><span class="logos l60">&nbsp;</span></a>
<div class="odds-nowrp" xodd="xzoxfxzox">2.62</div> // <- 2.62 is the numer i need
```

For full path see this screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of code and target number]

What library would do this best? (I know Jsoup cant do it) I have searched a few like:

- HtmlUnit
- Java Script Engine
- Apache Commons BSF
- Rhino

But i cant really make sense of it or find any examples for android which look like my problem

Comment: Do you want to doit from javascript? why do you say is something from a url if the value is not even in the _<a>_? If what you want is simply get that value from a <div> tag you could do something like `document.getElementById("MyDivId").value`, where `<div class="odds-nowrp" xodd="xzoxfxzox" id="MyDivId">2.62</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> or find any examples for android which look like my problem

You need it for android?

Pretty much any library allowing DOM traversing will allow you to do this providing you know how to find your value.

- is this value exactly at the same position in DOM every time?
- is it wrapped by an easy to identify element? i.e. with a static ID
- are there any other value that look alike in the DOM that you don't want?

Based on that, using JQuery for example, you could select it like this :

```
$('.table-main td.center > a[href^="/bookmaker"] + div[xodd]')
```

or this:

```
$('.table-main tr:nth-child(3) div.odds-nowrp[xodd]')
```

Comment: Oh yea, i forgot, im making an android app!
And yes the number is in the exact same position/table all the time
And i think there is an identifier, since the "odds-nowrp" is always there and first appears there:
<div class="odds-nowrp" xodd="xzoxfxzox">2.62</div>

Comment: @Yoshidk if it's always the same nth row you should try `$('.table-main tr:nth-child(3) div.odds-nowrp[xodd]')` see [API doc](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Comment: Yea just picking the same nth row everytime would work!
But i think i need this a bit more basic.. Im making this as an android app, so how do I include JQuery to eclipse? I can download "jquery-1.10.0.js" but i cannot include this as a *.jar lib?

Comment: @Yoshidk if you are making a pure Java Android app then retag your post and change the title because I tought you were looking for a javascript solution

Comment: Oh yea, i guess that was confusing us all.. I have reposted this to make it clear..

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery:

```
var number = $(".odds-nowrp").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use regex if you have the url already in escaped string format

```
reg = /[A-z\"\>\<=?()0-9 \/]*(\d+.\d+)[A-z\"\>\<=?()0-9 \/]*/
reg.exec(url)[1] // this will return your number
```

if it's already rendered and the xodd value doesn't change, you could do something like this

```
document.querySelectorAll('.odds-nowrp[xodd=xzoxfxzox]')[0].innerText
```

Comment: I should have made it clear that im making an android app, and im a noob!
Is the regex a library like Jsoup? Because i cant find any basic examples which fit to an android project

Also the "xodd" DOES change, but it changes to something random and i have no use of it, i just need the number

Comment: regex exists in all javascript , so if your andorid app is based on html5 , rather than native - ie your mostly working with javascript not java - you just use that regex in your javascript. I guess one question is if you have the string as  whole or you're trying to select from the dom nodes.